# Mercurial Clone (Kiln) repository to Bluehost

Tags: mercurial, clone, bluehost

Yesterday I installed mercurial on bluehost by following the instructions found here.http://bugtracker.gttools.com/public/wiki/bluehost/Mercurial

When I tried to clone one repository from kiln using :
`hg clone kiln_repository_url/devel`, to  `/home/yourusername/public_html/hg/repos/projectA` on bluehost, it is giving http error 404: Not Found.

Please help me in cloning the repositories from kiln to bluehost.

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: `hg clone kiln`? Is this you, Joel the Apostle, posting anonymously?

Comment: Hey, You are mistaken. This is not Joel, this is Raj. here what I meant is: hg clone kiln_repository_url/devel.

Comment: Sorry Raj, that's my bad joke. You know who created Kiln and co-created StackOverflow, I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you've specified the full URL, including the protocol:

```
hg clone https://example.kilnhg.com/Repo/...
```

Also double check that you have the full url.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you need to specify something other than `kiln` for the repository host, since Bluehost probably isn't able to resolve `kiln` via DNS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you know how to clone from kiln to bluehost?